# Unable to parse HTTP Request

Tags: api, parsing, katalon-studio, web-api-testing

I'm trying to parse my URL with wildcards. The problem appears when I try to parse long strings with a wildcard. For example, my URL looks like this:

```
http://testapi.com/v1/cards/%s/reissue?DesignId=%s&Comment=%s
```

and this is my code:

```
get_object.setRestUrl(String.format(url, card_id, design_id, comment))
```

When `comment = "Something"` it works, but when `comment = "Something something"`, it goes on an error and says that it is "Unable to parse HTTP request".

How is it possible to make suitable my code with long strings with wildcards? I know that when typing long string it gives URL that looks like this:

```
http://testapi.com/v1/cards/1/Block?reasonId=1&comment=Something%20like%20that%20example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to modify with `comment.replace(" ", "%20")`, and now it works fine, even when there are no spaces.

Source : https://forum.katalon.com/t/getting-an-error-unable-to-parse-http-request/17685

P.S 
If it is not allowed to post answer from another site, I will remove it.

Comment: It is allowed. However, you are encouraged to write the important part of the solution, so the answer remains on SO even if the outside link is removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it:

get_object.setRestUrl(String.format(url, card_id, design_id, comment.replace(" ", "%20")))

More information could be found at https://forum.katalon.com/t/getting-an-error-unable-to-parse-http-request/17685

Comment: thanks for your attention, I've already did it according to that link :)